# Fear of holding something to the air

Tags: phobias

I have this thing that when someone holds something out into air from the high places i think of it dropping. Whenever someone hold their phone out from the 3ed floor for example i start panicking. I CANT LOOK. it can be anything. A water bottle, a rock or maybe if they just slightly Lean against the railing... What is this?? A phobia?

Comment: Arguably, OP has a form of [**barophobia**](http://www.phobiasource.com/barophobia-fear-of-gravity/)  – *Fear of gravity*.

Answer (score 1):

**batophobia** [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/batophobia)

```
> The fear of high objects or of high objects falling down
```

Who knew? lol It likely mean to fall down upon one's self though.

Answer (score 0):

Many people are afraid of heights but the term [**acrophobia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acrophobia) is used to mean rather more - the body starts to react physically. But you are not at a height yourself.

This page: [Health Check: why are some people afraid of heights?](http://theconversation.com/health-check-why-are-some-people-afraid-of-heights-82893) says:

> When faced with heights or anticipating them, their sympathetic
>   nervous system is aroused, as if preparing the body for an emergency.
>   This arousal helps either approach or escape from a threat (commonly
>   known as the fight-or-flight response).

In your case it seems to be the *anticipation* of the danger and not the danger itself, so the term **acrophobia** may well apply to your experience.